# Google Places SDK for iOS equivalent of Google Places API call

Tags: swiftui, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am building an IOS app using SwiftUI and I have decided to use Google Places as it returns better results than MapKit. I am running into some trouble figuring out the use of Places API and. Places SDK for IOS.
I would like to know what is the Places SDK for iOS equivalent of the following Places API text search call which I am using to find all "sports clubs" near me:

```
var urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=\(query)&key=\(googleApiKey)"
```

SDK Current Place only returns places nearby, and SDK Autocomplete only returns 5 results.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Looking at their [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/), that feature is not yet available on Places SDK for iOS. So making that Text Search web request is your only option.

There is however an existing feature request to add that functionality in that SDK. If you are interested in this issue, visit the Issue Tracker at the link below, and star the issue. This will subscribe you to receive technical updates on the issue. Starring the issue also provides them with valuable feedback on the importance of the issue to their customers, and increases the issue's priority with their product engineering team.

You can view, and star the issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/35829470